# vsftpd can not connect from the same network

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I have a problem I receive the message that connection is timed-out. I can connect locally. It has a default config, both hosts are in the same network. I use Ubuntu and svftpd.

What I did:

1. I have checked firewalls (they were unconfigured)

   `iptables -F`
   `ufw disable`
2. I didn't change the config file.
3. Service is running.
4. I can connect from localhost and by ip (192.168.1.2) from host where server is running.
5. I receive the error message: "Connection timed out... Could not connect to server" on the other host when I try to connect.

Comment: You have given far too little information to allow a diagnosis. Please expand your question to include details of your network configuration and of what works and what doesn't.

Comment: I don't know what kind of information do you need. Please ask for some command output.

Comment: How are you trying to connect when you get the error?

Comment: I use Filezilla. I entered host user and password.

Comment: How does this differ from when you connect by IP?

Comment: I always connected using IP and always used Filezilla.

Comment: Can you `ping 192.168.1.2` from the other machine? Have you disabled the firewall on both machines?

Comment: it was uwf on the client side. After disabling everything works. Thank you for help.

Comment: Glad it's sorted.